# Можно ли сказать "российская и французская почты"?

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте! Будет ли верно сказать "российская и французская почта работает" или правильно "российская и французская почты работают"?

Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Российская и французская **почты** (почтовые системы) **работают** (по разным моделям). В этом примере  делается сравнение **двух систем**, поэтому используется множественное число.

Но: Эта модель характерна для российской и французской почты. В этом предложении  мы рассматриваем каждую почтовую систему **в  отдельности.**

Здесь "почта" используется, скорее,  в значении "почтовая система", а не "почтамт".

**ПОЧТА**, -ы; ж. [польск. poezta из итал.] 1. Учреждение связи; здание, помещение, где находится это учреждение. 2. Пересылка, доставка чего-л. средствами таких учреждений. **ПОЧТАМТ**, -а; м. [от нем. Postamt] Главное почтовое учреждение города, осуществляющее все виды телеграфной и телефонной связи; здание, помещение, где находится это учреждение.

Answer (score 0):

Структуры или учреждения разных стран словом в единственном числе называть неверно, ну разве только в разговоре (легче выговаривается). Это разные, хотя и профильные, организации. Под почтой в этом контексте подразумевается *почтамт*, так замените её этим словом, чтобы почувствовать разницу между правильным и неправильным более отчётливо. Можно, чего уж там, подставить слово *президент*.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае нужно нужно мн. ч.

> Имя существительное ставится в форме множественного числа:
>
> 1) если подчеркивается наличие нескольких предметов, например:
>   московский и горьковский автозаводы; токарный и фрезерный станки,
>   золотая и серебряная медали...

**ЛИТЕРАТУРНОЕ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЕ ТЕКСТА. Розенталь Д. Э.**